# JSONObject не выводит массив при вызове метода toString

Tags: java, json

Делаю задачу и при преобразовании объекта в json строку  почему то не выводится массив типа string
создавал также массив в конструкторе  результат такой же
в чем причина?

вывод - {"data":30,"contact":{"phone":"11-111"},"text":"someText","value":false}

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "jsonexample")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

public class JsonExample {

    @XmlAttribute
    private boolean value;
    @XmlAttribute
    private int data;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String text;
    private Contact contact;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "arrays")
    @XmlElement(name = "array")
    private static String[] arrays;

    public JsonExample(boolean value, int data, String text, Contact contact, String[] array) {
        this.value = value;
        this.data = data;
        this.text = text;
        this.contact = contact;
        arrays = array;
    }

    public boolean isValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public static String[] getArrays() {
        return arrays;
    }

    public JsonExample() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JsonExample{" + "value=" + value + ", data=" + data + ", text='" + text + '\'' + ", contact=" + contact
                + ", array=" + Arrays.toString(arrays) + '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, IOException {

        /* JSONObject из json-строки строки */
        JSONObject jsonContact = new JSONObject("{\"phone\":\"+7(924)111-111-11-11\"}");

        /* JSONArray из ArrayList */
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("One");
        list.add("Two");
        JSONArray jsonArrays = new JSONArray(list);

        /* JSONObject напрямую методом put */
        String[] array = new String[] {"one", "two", "three"};
        final JsonExample example = new JsonExample(false, 30, "someText", new Contact("11-111"),array);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("boolean", example.isValue());
        jsonObject.put("data", example.getData());
        jsonObject.put("text", example.getText());
        jsonObject.put("contact", jsonContact);
        jsonObject.put("arrays", jsonArrays);
        /* Выведем результат в консоль */
        System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
        /* Преобразуем объект в json-строку */
        System.out.println( new JSONObject(example).toString());      
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите класс JsonExample

Comment: А в `JsonExample` есть ли поле с этим массивом?

Comment: отредактировал описание

Comment: решил. поле массива было статичное )